# Implementation of Editable Priority Queue

Tags: c++, c, heap-memory, priority-queue, dijkstra

I wanted to implement my own Priority Queue for Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm that stores shortest discovered distance to particular node and also allow editing it, so I thought to make heap that stores pointers to array with distances.

```
void heapify(int **h, int i, int size)
{
    int min =i;
    int l = 2*i;
    int r =l+1;
    if(l <= size && *h[l] < *h[i])
        min = l;
    else
        min =i;
    if(r <=size && *h[r] < *h[min])
        min =r;

    if(min!=i)
    {
        int *temp;
        temp = h[i];
        h[i] = h[min];
        h[min] = temp;
        heapify(h,min,size);
    }
}

void build(int **h,int size)
{
    int i; 
    for(i = size;i>0;i--)
        heapify(h,i,size);
}


int main()
{
    int a[100];
    int *h[99];
    int i;

    for(i=1;i<11;i++)
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    for(i= 11 ;i<100;i++)
        a[i] = INT_MAX ;
    a[0] =INT_MAX ;


    for(i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        h[i] = (a+i);
    }
    build(h,99);

    // printing elements of heap
    for(i=1;i<11;i++)
        printf("%d ", *h[i]);

    return 0;

}
```

How should I implement a function that restores heap property of h after change is made in a?

Comment: **Do not** access `h[99]`, which is out-of-range.

Comment: Even if I make it `int * h[100]`, It doesn't work

Comment: Please show us your input and expected output.

Comment: I updated the question to include input and output.

Comment: The expected output is what you shouldn't expect to heaps. Heaps will make sure that the parent of each node won't become bigger (in this case), but it won't assume which of childlen of a node will be bigger (or same).

Comment: By the way, the implementation of `heapify()` differs from what I know. I think you should call `heapify(h, i/2, size)` when `min==i && i>1`.

Comment: Sorry I just typed the expected output in a hurry.

Comment: Descriptions of heap generally assume one based indexing.  But C++ uses zero based indexing.  So either you need to adjust the heap rules to use zero based indexing (you did not) or you need to waste element 0 of the container (If you did that, it should be done more clearly).